# How to Capture notifications from system services in Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, notifications, toast

I know about Notification Listener in Windows 10.
[notification-listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener)

It says :
The notification listener provides access to a user's notifications. Simply call the GetNotificationsAsync method, and specify the type of notifications you want to get (currently, the only type of notifications supported are toast notifications).

We have user applications and system services.

Does this API allow us to capture toaster notifications or pop ups  from system service also?

secondly, what notifications it does not support?

Thanks a lot in advance for your time.

Comment: First sentence in the linked documentation: *"The notification listener provides access to **a user's** notifications."* In other words: You have to run code under a specific user's account to get notifications for that user, and only that user.

Comment: @IInspectable : suppose its same user, can we get notifications from services running for that user?

Comment: No. You're still going to have to run in that user's interactive session. Services run in Session 0. What you can do is launch an application that runs in a user's session from your service and have that application communicate with the service.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for replying. Apologies for not conveying the question correctly. I am referring to services which are already running in user. Example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/per-user-services-in-windows          such services send some notifications to the user. Can we capture them? If so, how??

Comment: Example Bluetooth service might say devices found to user by showing message popup. Can we capture it?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this API allow us to capture toast notifications from system service applications also?

`GetNotificationsAsync` method is under `Windows.UI.Notifications.Management` namespace, I'm afraid you can't use it in system service applications(.Net Framework assembly). And you need also enable  **User Notification Listener** capability, but system service applications has no such entry pointer to do this. So you can't use it in system service applications.

> secondly, what notifications it does not support?

Derive from [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.notificationkinds?view=winrt-19041),  `NotificationKinds` contains  `Toast` and `Unknown` type, there is no document to tell what is not support.

Comment: I meant notifications that come from system applications that are running in the same user account. Apologies zico for unclear questions.

Comment: Does system applications notification show in the notification center?